# Secure text entry for TextFiled

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am using textfiled for password entry with echomode password. but i want it should display characters while entering and after some time(one sec) or entering next char it should goto asterisks.

code:

```
TextField {
        id: inputtext
        height: parent.height
        width:parent.width
        font.family: "Helvetica"
        horizontalAlignment: TextInput.Center
        font.pointSize:  Math.round(28 * (main.height/1080))
        placeholderText:"Password"
        echoMode:TextInput.Password
    }
```

I tried it using text item which displays current enter key after some time i will make it invisible and moving text item based on cursor position.
code:

```
TextField {
    id: inputtext
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 200
    height: 20
    echoMode:TextInput.Password
    Text{
        id: showpwd
        text: "h"
        font.pointSize: 10
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    }
    onTextChanged: {
        showpwd.x = cursorPosition*7
        showpwd.text = text.charAt(cursorPosition-1);

    }
}
```

issue: still i can view asterisk behind the text item. could some one help me out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have done very little testing. But, it should give you the idea.

```
TextField {

    id: pwdField

    property string password: ""
    // could be ugly solution, but does the job
    property string replaceString: "*******************************************************************"
    property bool ignoreNext: false

    placeholderText: "some text"
    onTextChanged: {
        if (ignoreNext) return;
        var txtLength = text.length;
        if (txtLength === 0) {
            password = text;
            updateTimer.stop();
        } else {
            if (txtLength < password.length) {
                password = password.substring(0, txtLength);
                console.log(text, "pwd: ", password)
                return;
            } else if (txtLength > password.length) {
                password += text.charAt(txtLength - 1)
            }

            if (updateTimer.running) {
                obscureText();
                ignoreNext = true
                text = text.substring(0, txtLength - 1) + password.charAt(password.length - 1);
                ignoreNext = false
            }
            updateTimer.restart();
        }


        console.log(text, "pwd: ", password)
    }
    onEditingFinished: {
        updateTimer.stop();
        obscureText();
    }

    function obscureText() {
        ignoreNext = true;
        text = replaceString.substring(0, text.length);
        ignoreNext = false;
    }

    Timer {
        id: updateTimer
        running: false
        repeat: false
        interval: 1000
        onTriggered: pwdField.obscureText();
    }
}
```

issues you have to workaround:

- you can't really use `text` property anymore as it will give you all `*****`, use `password` and `onPasswordChanged` signal
- this solution won't work if user moves the cursor around using navigation keys

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution. `TextInput` has already got a property named `passwordMaskDelay` to handle such type of problems. See my solution.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should use `TextInput` instead of `TextField` because it's a basic element in `qml`. Let's take the following example for password entry, I'm using `passwordMaskDelay` property of `TextInput` which was introduced in `Qt` 5.4.

```
Rectangle {
    id: container
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "yellow"

    TextInput {
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        id: text2
        echoMode: TextInput.Normal
        font.pixelSize: 20; font.bold: true
        text: "Enter text here..."
        width: container.width - 40 ;
        focus: true
        passwordMaskDelay: 1000
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            text2.text = "";
            text2.echoMode = TextInput.Password;
        }
    }
}
```

I think you wanted a transparent background, I've kept that in mind. You can experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. But I think it's impossible to override visible text of `TextField` in this way. As for solution I can offer only this lame workaround:

```
TextField {
    id: inputtext
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    echoMode:TextInput.Password
    horizontalAlignment: TextInput.Center
    onEditingFinished: mask.visible = false
    Rectangle {
        id:  mask
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "white"
        border.width: 1
        border.color: "#999"
        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            font: inputtext.font
            text: new Array(inputtext.text.length).join( "*" ) + inputtext.text.charAt(inputtext.text.length - 1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but some how i feel its not good still i followed same logic. could check updated code